# Windows' command return dates in 2066?

Tags: windows-10, timestamp

On our `Windows 10 Entreprise LTSC 10.0.17763` systems, if I run:

`cscript c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv | findstr "Trusted Time:`

I get timestamps in **2066!**, e.g. `1/17/2066 4:28:53 AM`.

I have those systems synchronizing with a local ntp time server via `w32tm`.
Running `date /T` and `time /T` return the correct date and time.

What could cause that timestamp to be so off?

Also, I didn't check all our LTSC systems, but in the ones I did, there is an entry in `Event Viewer`, `Custom Views`, `Administrative Events`, with a timestamp in `1/17/20666`, for a `Witness Client Initialization` failure.

Comment: Is your system recording any EventID 261 and 259?  You can [edit] your question instead of replying with a comment.

Comment: Can you provide the value of Trusted Time from the following PowerShell command: `Get-CimInstance -Class SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter 'ProductKeyId != NULL' | Select-Object -Property Name, Description, LicenseStatus, EvaluationEndDate, PartialProductKey, ProductKeyChannel, RemainingAppRearmCount, trustedTime, UseLicenseUrl, ValidationUrl`

Comment: @Ramhound  No event ID 261 nor 259, so far, as I've cleaned up all the logs this morning and rebooted. Trusted Time from Power Shell command is 1/17/2066 4:28:55 AM (same as reported by slmgr.vbs) and curiously Evaluation End Date is 12/31/1600 4:00::00 PM

Comment: I suspect your machine is not talking to your KMS at all, might explain the reason, you were getting activation errors (per your other question).

Comment: @Ramhound  This happens on all my LTSC systems, whether LicenseStatus as returned from CimInstance, as above, returns 1 (Licensed) or 5 (Notification), this last one only on the machine I can't activate per my other question.  All other installations return 1.

Comment: *A file time is a 64-bit value that represents the number of 100-nanosecond intervals that have elapsed since 12:00 A.M. January 1, 1601 Coordinated Universal Time (UTC).* so you are in a -8 hours time zone - maybe California.. This means the value is zero.

Comment: Your local ntp time server must be glitching, as it's the common denominator of these servers.

Comment: Having an incorrect time from your NTP would explain the activation errors.  You have to understand, in order to determine when the next time the machine must contact your KMS (180 days) it must have an accurate representation of the current date.  Yes; -8 UTC would be California

Comment: @user1292580  That's maybe for the 1601 EvaluationEndDate, but not for the 2066 date

Comment: @harrymc Can you define glitching? I have over 50 boxes, no internet access, using a  NTP server on a linux box, with internet access, using pool.ntp.org servers, and all machines seem to be in sync to sub-second accuracy.

Comment: @ramhound All machines have the correct time to subsecond accuracy. date and time report the correct PDT time

Comment: @HASM - What type of eventID is Witness Client Initialization, I cannot find a single relevant article on it, please [edit] your question and include some of the information you have provided in a comment. Looking at the output I suggested several hours ago, `EvaluationEndDate` is supposed to be `12/31/1600 6:00:00 PM` while connected to a KMS.  I would be interesting in the value of `ProductKeyChannel` one a machine that is properly activated.

Comment: I have an updated command, I am looking for specific information from both a working KMS client, a KMS client that isn't working, and the KMS host itself.  Please provide the formatted output as an [edit] to your question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/127968/discussion-between-ramhound-and-hasm).

Comment: Here is the command: Here is the command: `Get-CimInstance -Class SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter 'ProductKeyId != NULL' | Select-Object -Property Name, Description, LicenseStatus, EvaluationEndDate, ProductKeyChannel, RemainingAppRearmCount, trustedTime, UseLicenseUrl, ValidationUrl, GenuineStatus, GracePeriodRemaining, IsKeyManagementServiceMachine, KeyManagementServiceFailedRequests, KeyManagementServiceNotificationRequests, KeyManagementServiceTotalRequests, KeyManagementServiceUnlicensedRequests, LicenseStatusReason, RequiredClientCount`

Comment: "Glitching", as in from time to time reporting a wrong year. How often do the clients solicit the ntp server?

Comment: @harrymc Doubt there are any glitches.  SpecialPollInterval is set to 3600 s.  Event logs, on one machine, point to time being updated every 15 minutes by about 0.005 s.  Date  always correct.

Comment: As this is happening on multiple machine, it's either the time server, communication problem with that server, or some installed application.

Comment: @harrymc All these machines are on an isolated subnet with no internet access. Wondering if this has anything to do with it, and only on Win10.  All other 40+ Win7 machines in the same subnet return the proper time, thus no problems getting the time from the time server.  All machines are w32tm and slmgr configured identically.

Comment: The machines that show the problem might have something in common?

Comment: @harrymc The only commonality is that they are all Windows 10 Enterprise LTSC build 10.0.17763.  Besides that they are, where possible, pretty much configured as the Windows 7 machines and loaded, with minor variants, with the same non-Microsoft software.

Comment: The [Witness Client initialization failed](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/event-1-smb-witness-client-initialization) message probably means that you have network or cluster problems.

Comment: @harrymc Not worried about the WitnessClient error, just curious about the timestamp on the error. There are other entries with the same timestamp.  To clear those logs one needs to change permission on the log files, thus a bit of a pain to get rid of them. I just cleared them and I believe they won't come back.